# Returning error when trying to insert document with non-existent field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I want to insert a new document which consists of **two** strings into myindex/mytype

> { "name" : "joe", "city": "ny" }

BUT mytype consist only of **one** string field: "name"

In this case, I want the indexing to fail, and that elasticsearch will return an error. How do I do that?
Right now, it creates a new document :frowning:

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` setting of mapping.

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "dynamic":      "strict", 
            "properties": {
                "name":  { "type": "string"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- If you set true, which is the default, adding new fields dynamically.
- If you set false, ignoring new fields.
- If you set strict, elasticsearch throw an exception if an unknown field is encountered.

Source : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html